# Tengo un programa de descargas con conexiones paralelas, por rangos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Resulta que tengo un código para descargar un programa mediante paralelismo pero resulta que descarga algunos archivos, pero en algunas páginas se queda finalizando pero no llega al final, alguien que me diga que es lo que esta pasando, de antemano gracias por su respuesta.

```
import urllib.request
import threading
import time
rangos_a_unir={}
rangos_unir_comprobacion={}

def peso_archivo_rangos_unir(url):

    c=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    c=int(c.getheader('Content-Length'))
    print("TAMAÑO DEL ARCHIVO",c)

    c=int(c//50)+1
    d=c
    for i in range(50):
        if i==0:
            rangos_a_unir[0]=c
        else:

            rangos_a_unir[(c-d)+1]=c
        c=c+d
    print(rangos_a_unir)
    iniciar_descarga_paralela(url,rangos_unir_comprobacion)

def descarga_rangos(url,a,b):

    data= urllib.request.Request(url)

    data.add_header('Range',f'bytes={str(a)}-{str(b)}' )

    data=urllib.request.urlopen(data)
#try:
    data=data.read()
    rangos_unir_comprobacion[a]=data
    print(len(rangos_unir_comprobacion))
    time.sleep(1)
#except:
#   rangos_unir_comprobacion[a]=data



def reconstruccion_datos(rangos):
    while True:
    
    
        if len(rangos)==50:
            print("==============")
            print("claves")
            print("===========")
            print(rangos.keys())

            print("===========")
            print("RANGOS ORDENADOS")
            print("==============")
            lista_rangos_ordenados=sorted(rangos)
            with open("archivo_prueba.mp4", "wb") as f:
                for i in range(len(lista_rangos_ordenados)):
                    f.write(rangos[lista_rangos_ordenados[i]])

            break
    

  def iniciar_descarga_paralela(url,rangos_unir_comprobacion):
       a=0
       for i in rangos_a_unir:
          try:
             thread=threading.Thread(target=descarga_rangos, args=(url,i,rangos_a_unir[i],))
             thread.start()
          except:
             thread=threading.Thread(target=descarga_rangos, args=(url,i,rangos_a_unir[i],))
             thread.start()
             print("HUBO ERROR")
          a+=1
      thread2=threading.Thread(target=reconstruccion_datos, args=(rangos_unir_comprobacion,))
      thread2.start()



peso_archivo_rangos_unir('https://r1---sn-51uxj5-88je.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1619464617&ei=KaGGYNN2utbMtQ_hrqPQDA&ip=186.190.226.94&id=43fd0242791f27dd&itag=18&source=blogger&mh=ZB&mm=31&mn=sn-51uxj5-88je&ms=au&mv=m&mvi=1&pl=24&susc=bl&mime=video/mp4&vprv=1&dur=1389.273&lmt=1353276753600599&mt=1619435563&sparams=expire,ei,ip,id,itag,source,susc,mime,vprv,dur,lmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRQIgXqDpKPgfRfAQIvIsZTCobwFbqALa8HzGk6KNAoH68sACIQDqWTh8UOoAFAFcqpMDGpa8BfK39IvWdZ3PR07pPMUN5g%3D%3D&lsparams=mh,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRQIgOAC2NX7SHTBBDv3LVRnEfxVArgwgacrvKXBwj4Y5dqgCIQDSz3X2CWa5KwEgwiB_Jp80UeNt55weUIXIDHMbNuWBCA%3D%3D&cpn=jMUIkJJO2CL-_Sgp&c=WEB_EMBEDDED_PLAYER&cver=1.20210421.1.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

Para la persona que le sea util el programa, ya encontre la solución, y es que la ip del servidor piensa que le haremos DDOS y por eso nos cierra la conexión, la solución es hacer un time.sleep() y ya queda

```
import urllib.request
import threading
import time
rangos_a_unir={}
rangos_unir_comprobacion={}
print("=====================================================")
print("CREADOR JHOAN BARRERA")
print("=====================================================")
extension=input("ESCRIBE LA EXTENSION DEL ARCHIVO: ")
def peso_archivo_rangos_unir(url):

    c=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    c=int(c.getheader('Content-Length'))
    print("TAMAÑO DEL ARCHIVO",c)

    c=int(c//50)+1
    d=c
    for i in range(50):
        if i==0:
            rangos_a_unir[0]=c
        else:

            rangos_a_unir[(c-d)+1]=c
        c=c+d
    print(rangos_a_unir)
    iniciar_descarga_paralela(url,rangos_unir_comprobacion)

def descarga_rangos(url,a,b):
    
    data= urllib.request.Request(url)

    data.add_header('Range',f'bytes={str(a)}-{str(b)}' )

    data=urllib.request.urlopen(data)
    #try:
    data=data.read()
    rangos_unir_comprobacion[a]=data
    print(len(rangos_unir_comprobacion))

    #except:
    #   rangos_unir_comprobacion[a]=data

    

def reconstruccion_datos(rangos):
    while True:
        
        
        if len(rangos)==50:
            print("==============")
            print("claves")
            print("===========")
            print(rangos.keys())

            print("===========")
            print("RANGOS ORDENADOS")
            print("==============")
            lista_rangos_ordenados=sorted(rangos)
            with open("archivo_descargado.{}".format(extension), "wb") as f:
                for i in range(len(lista_rangos_ordenados)):
                    f.write(rangos[lista_rangos_ordenados[i]])

            break
        

def iniciar_descarga_paralela(url,rangos_unir_comprobacion):
    a=0
    for i in rangos_a_unir:
        try:
            thread=threading.Thread(target=descarga_rangos, args=(url,i,rangos_a_unir[i],))
            thread.start()
        except:
            thread=threading.Thread(target=descarga_rangos, args=(url,i,rangos_a_unir[i],))
            thread.start()
            print("HUBO ERROR")
        a+=1
        time.sleep(1.5)
    thread2=threading.Thread(target=reconstruccion_datos, args=(rangos_unir_comprobacion,))
    thread2.start()

peso_archivo_rangos_unir(f"{input('ESCRIBE TU URL: ')}")
```

Comment: Este respuesta quedaría mucho mas completa si adjuntas también como quedaría el código, esto por si algún otro usuario tiene el mismo problema comprenda como lo hiciste. ;)